# Delphi FastReports change globally Boolean text True/False to Yes/No?

Tags: delphi, fastreport

Is anyway to change printed text for boolean values in FastReports?

Comment: Yes you can do it, first edit your question and add more details please.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it as follow :

1- On the **Data tree**  drag and drop  your `Boolean` field in the Band.

2- Double click on the `Memo`.

3- Click on the **Format** Tab.

4- Choose `Boolean` from the category.

5- Choose **Yes/No** from the **Format**.

6- Click **OK** button.

**Update:**

If you not in design mode then :

```
Var Mem : TfrxMemoView;
Mem := frxReport1.FindObject('MyMemo') as TfrxMemoView;
Mem.DisplayFormat.Kind:=fkBoolean;
Mem.DisplayFormat.FormatStr:='No,Yes';
```

Comment: I dynamically create reports with OnManualBuild,not in design mode.

Comment: You can also put manually this mask on your manually created TfrxMemoViews (DisplayFormat.FormatStr property).

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Page.OnBeforePrint()` event and loop through controls replacing their `Text` property.

```
procedure Page1OnBeforePrint(Sender: TfrxComponent);
var
   Obj  : TObject;
   Memo : TFrxMemoView;                                                              
   i    : Integer;                                   
begin                                                                                                                         
   for i:=0 to Sender.Objects.Count -1 do
   begin
     Obj := Sender.Objects[i];
     if (Obj is TfrxMemoView) then
     begin                       
       Memo := TfrxMemoView(Obj);             
       if (UpperCase(trim(Memo.Text))='FALSE') then Memo.Text := 'No';
       if (UpperCase(trim(Memo.Text))='TRUE') then Memo.Text := 'Yes';                                                                           
     end;                                      
   end;                  
end;
```

Maybe it's not perfect solution, but it shows how to iterate through page objects.